# Why does this does not print nor terminate?

Tags: c++

I had coaching today and we wrote this little code. What it does is obvious so I wont explain in details. After I run it and type something in, it does not print anything, and does not terminate either. If I switch chars for ints, it works fine. What is wrong with this code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "wpisz zdanie: ";
    string zdanie;
    getline(cin, zdanie);

    int tab[256];
    for(char i=0; i<=255; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<=zdanie.size()-1; i++)
    {
        tab[zdanie[i]]++;
    }

    for(char i=0; i<=255; i++)
    {
        if(i>='0' && i<='Z')
        {
            cout << (char)i << " -> " << tab[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the `char` data type has values from -128 to 127, so no matter how much you increment them, they will never reach 255. They will just loop back to -128 after going over 127. You can try using `unsigned char` or `int`.

Comment: Thank you. You were very helpful. Unsigned char did not work for some reason. Int does work fine.

Comment: @ArekBulski On typical 8-bit byte machines, the `unsigned char` type will have value range [0, 255]. Thus, the condition `i<=255` in your `for` loop will **always** be true. Think about it: `<=` means "less than **or equal**", and even 255 is less than **or equal** than 255. The loop will be infinite, that's why `unsigned char` will not work.